# SQL Server Yesterdays Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a count of all of yesterdays rows. The query i have runs good but does not pick up null values. Is there a way i can query a count of null and non null values?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0) as Received_Date,
COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
FROM Table CD, 
CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD 
WHERE CD.ccid = RD.ccid
and CompletedDate >= DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,1,getdate()),0)
and CompletedDate < DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()),0)
AND CatID in('cat0014')
AND IncomingType <> 'RITS'
AND status = 'Completed'
```

Comment: The problem you have is that you are filtering the data by more conditions, not just by yeterday’s date

Comment: It has been more than 25 years now that your join syntax has been out of date. Time to start using the more current join syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: It's 2018, not 1989. Come join the modern day! [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You *just* beat me to it @SeanLange . :)

Comment: @Larnu LOL!!!!!

Comment: @SeanLange I do love Bertrand's "Bad habits" pack (apart from not using `AS` syntax on Aliasing, that's definitely a preference thing).

Comment: @Larnu I agree. Although I have come to prefer Alias = Expression these days. Makes debugging easier for me since the column name is always first.

Comment: This is some hella old script haha maybe its time to learn some new things bud :)

Comment: First, don't use comma-syntax `JOIN`s. Use an actual `INNER JOIN`. Can a `CompletedDate` be greater than today? If not, then you don't need your second `CompletedDate` filter. In fact, you may be doing too much with your date math to simply get records from yesterday. How do you define "yesterday", you should just be able to subtract one day. Which column is it that's giving you `NULL` values that aren't being counted?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `CompletedDate` to a date with no time and make it equal yesterdays date with no time (from `GETDATE()`) and use correct `JOIN` code.

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0) as Received_Date,
COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
FROM Table CD
LEFT JOIN CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD ON CD.ccid = RD.ccid
WHERE dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,CompletedDate),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND CatID IN ('cat0014')
AND IncomingType != 'RITS'
AND status = 'Completed'
```

Return `NULL`s:

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0) as Received_Date,
COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
FROM Table CD
LEFT JOIN CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD ON CD.ccid = RD.ccid
WHERE dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,CompletedDate),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND (CatID IN ('cat0014') OR CatID IS NULL)
AND (IncomingType != 'RITS' OR IncomingType IS NULL)
AND (status = 'Completed' OR status IS NULL)
```

Comment: Using datediff functions on the CompletedDate column in the Where clause will make it NON-SARGable and could lead to performance degradation. We could use the original >=, < approach from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix your query and do:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE) as Received_Date,
       COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
FROM Table CD JOIN
     CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD 
     ON CD.ccid = RD.ccid
WHERE CompletedDate >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE) AND
      CompletedDate < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) AND
      CatID IN ('cat0014') AND
      IncomingType <> 'RITS' AND
      status = 'Completed';
```

For the date part, you could also do:

CAST(CompletedDate as DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE)

This version is even index-safe in SQL Server (although not necessarily in other databases).

Notes:

- The `DATE` data type considerably simplifies your calculations.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- You should qualify all column names so you (and anyone reading the query) knows what table the column comes from.

Comment: Thank you all! Can you please explain your last bullet point on qualifying all column names?

Comment: @ajburnett34 . . . Qualifying column names means that you include the table alias.  For instance, either `rd.status` or `cd.status`.